# Calculating entropy change with Tds relations

Tags: thermodynamics

The problem I am trying to solve is:

*A copper block weighing 20 kg is dropped into a large pool of water. The water temperature is 22°C and the temperature of the copper block when it is dropped into the water is 95°C. After a while, thermal equilibrium is reached  between the copper block and the water. Calculate the total entropy change during the process.Use constant specific heat capacity at room temperature.*

When calculating the entrophy for when the copper block is dropped in the pool these steps are taken:

[image]

My question is how am I supposed to find *C<sub>cu</sub>*? And why is mass supposed to be taken into consideration?

Comment: What resources have you discovered that provide you with specific heat capacities? What are the units on each of the terms? These insights will start you on the right road to answer your questions.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the second half of the question first, $c_{\textsf{Cu}}$ is the quantity commonly known as the *specific* heat capacity of copper, where "specific" means "per mass".  Hence, to find the heat capacity of any given sample of copper, one has to multiply the specific heat capacity by the mass.

For the first half of the question: unless you're in some sort of closed exam conditions, you can look up the value of $c_{\textsf{Cu}}$ in a lookup table, e.g. [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20180411172317/http://www.kayelaby.npl.co.uk/general_physics/2_3/2_3_6.html).